# UNIQUE constraint failed: query_table.ID (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY[1555]

Tags: android, android-room

I have the following entity in my project -

```java
@Entity(tableName = "query_table")
public class QueryModel {


    @PrimaryKey
    private int ID;

    private int productID;

    private String vendorName;

    private String productName;

    private String lateTimeUpdated;

    public QueryModel(String vendorName, String productName, String lateTimeUpdated, int productID) {
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.lateTimeUpdated = lateTimeUpdated;
        this.productID = productID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getProductID() {
        return productID;
    }

    public void setProductID(int productID) {
        this.productID = productID;
    }

    public String getVendorName() {
        return vendorName;
    }

    public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getLateTimeUpdated() {
        return lateTimeUpdated;
    }

    public void setLateTimeUpdated(String lateTimeUpdated) {
        this.lateTimeUpdated = lateTimeUpdated;
    }
}
```

for some reasons, I get the following error when starting to populate the local db -

`UNIQUE constraint failed: query_table.ID (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY[1555]`

I understand it has something to do with me getting the same value again and again and overriding it which makes it crash, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the constructor you don't pass the `id` field and as I can see you don't initialize it in general.

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

    private int ID;
```

If you go like this, does anything change? How can it be Primary key if it is null?